# How can I generate/create new spring beans at runtime with a bean definition object?

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control, generator, javabeans

I am new to Spring, and I would like to write a beanGenerator for a template bean. I would like to use this generator to overcome thread-safe concerns. Can anyone help me to add / modify the code to make this work? It's kind of hard to describe my real issue, so I abstract the issue in the following code:

```
abstract class BeanDefinition {

  abstract public void preprocess();

}

// now we have 1st user specific bean :
class UserSpecifiedBeanDefinition extends BeanDefinition{

  @override
  public void preprocess() {
     // do something
  }

}


// we could have more user-specific beans that extend BeanDefinition
....




// Following generator class is used to generate beans

public class BeanGenerator {

  private BeanDefinition beanDefinition;
  public BeanGenerator(BeanDefinition beanDefinition) {
    this.beanDefinition = beanDefinition;
  }
  public generate() {
    BeanDefinition newBean = // create new bean based on beanDefinition? how can I make this work??
    newBean.preprocess();
    return newBean;
  }
}

// In spring.xml, I would like to use them like:
<bean id="generator1" class="com.xxx.xxx.BeanGenerator">
    <constructor-arg name="beanDefinition" ref="userSpecifiedBeanDefinition"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: have you looked in beans of scope prototype ?

Comment: @Thierry Yes, but I haven't thought of a way of using prototype scope in this case. Can you point me a bit more on this? In this case, I have an abstract bean definition, and later users will define their own concrete bean definitions, and the generator will generate beans based on different concrete definitions.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you have a constructor without parameters. Use reflection to instantiate class

```
Class c = BeanGenerator.class.getClassLoader().loadClass(beanDefinition.getBeanClassName());
Constructor con = c.getConstructor();
Object instance = con.newInstance();
```

If you have constructor with parameters the logic should be changed to select correct constructor and pass the parameters to the `newInstance()` call